# How to combine multiple variables into one selector

Tags: jquery

I have 2 jquery vars:

```
var contVar = $('#container');
var linkNameVar = $(this).attr('id'); //for example <div id="test">
```

What I need is to combine them to access `#container .test`, i.e. for it to look like:

```
$(contVar .linkNameVar)
```

How do I:

1. add a `.` in front of `linkName` to turn it into a class.
2. then combine the 2 variables into 1 selector.

I looked at the `.add()` documentation but it doesn't seem to be what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you could use the second parameter as the context for selector.

```
$('.'+linkNameVar, contVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
contvar.find('.' + linkNameVar)
```

Comment: thank you, this works well also, I chose the other answer because they answered me first.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourNode = $('.' + linkNameVar, contVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the `<div id-"test">` is a child of `<div id="container">` then you have to do :-

```
var contVar = $('#container');
var linkNameVar = $(this).attr('id'); //for example <div id="test">
var linkNameVar1 = $(this).attr('class'); // for example <div class="test">

contVar.children('#'+linkNameVar); // if test is an ID then like this
contVar.children('.'+linkNameVar1); // if test is a class then like this
```

Let me know if there is any confusion or you have some other requirement.